# Function working fine in Chrome and IE but not in FireFox

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

It is the function that i am using to validate my form's name field. This code is working fine in Chrome and IE but not in FireFox.

When check it with firbug it gives this error:

```
chkForm is not defined
```

On this line:

```
if ( chkForm.name.value == "" ).
```

Thanks in advance

```
function uname()
{   
    if ( chkForm.name.value == "" )
    {
        alert("Please fill in Username box");
        chkForm.name.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is the html form

```
<form name="chkForm" id="chkForm" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return Form_Validator(this)">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="550" id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td width="135">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="138">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="215">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="135">Username</td>
        <td width="138">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="username" onblur="return uname()" size="20" class="input_s1_normal"></td>
        <td width="215">
        <div id="nameInfo" align="left"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="135">Email</td>
        <td width="138">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="20" class="input_s1_normal"></td>
        <td width="215">
        <div id="emailInfo" align="left"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>       
    <tr>
        <td width="135">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="138">
        <input type="submit" value="SAVE" name="B1" class="button_s1"></td>
        <td width="215">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: where do you define and initialize `chkForm`?

Comment: Yes please provide the HTML as well.

Answer (score 1):

Making an assumption here because can't see all of your code, by I assume you're relying on the fact that IE and Chrome allow access to the dom for elements with IDs through a global var of that ID.

You need to actually define the variable and get a reference to the node like so:

```
var chkForm = document.getElementById('chkForm');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether chkForm is defined or not like this.

Its may not be the ideal way to do that but you will get the general idea how to do that.

```
function uname()
{   
    if(!(chkForm)){
        chkForm = document.getElementByID('chkForm');
    }
    if ( chkForm.name.value == "" )
    {
        alert("Please fill in Username box");
        chkForm.name.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This will still throw an error. You need to check `if (typeof chkForm === "undefined")`

Answer (score 0):

Thanx to all of you. This code is working now after I add following line in my code

```
var chkForm = document.getElementById('chkForm');


function uname()
{   
    var chkForm = document.getElementById('chkForm');
    if ( chkForm.name.value == "" )
    {
        alert("Please fill in Username box");
        chkForm.name.focus();
        return false;
    }
     return true;
}
```

Bundles of Thanks :-)
Sohail Ahmad

Comment: But it is not focusing back to username field after alert

    chkForm.name.focus();